# Open a link and autoscroll to specific div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autoscroll

I have this code that when you open a link it will scroll to the specific div on that page.

**collection.html**

```
<a id='about' href="index.html">about</a>
```

**index.html**

```
<div id='#moreInfo>contents here</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#moreInfo").offset().top
           }, 1000);
   })
</script>
```

My problem is whenever I load the **index.html**, it always scrolls to the **moreInfo** div. What I want is when I'm on **collection.html** and I click on the **about** link, it will redirect to **index.html** then scroll smoothly to the **moreInfo** div.

I'll appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do this is just to have your link point to a location hash.

```
<a id='about' href="index.html#moreInfo">about</a>
```

Then, in your JavaScript you could just check if the person came from that link.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      if (window.location.hash == "#moreInfo") {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#moreInfo").offset().top
         }, 1000);
      }
   });
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<a id='about' href="index.html#moreInfo">about</a>` ... without the "/"?

Comment: @DelightedD0D That is correct. Also I'm not sure that this solution will work, since if I'm not mistaken the browser will automatically snap to the `moreInfo` section before the javascript gets a chance to smooth scroll there.

Comment: Yes @DelightedD0D, you're correct and I've edited. I'm curious too as to Maximillian's comment, as I didn't get to test it exactly as it is. Although I do have very similar things working for me in production code at the moment.

Comment: Actually, @MaximillianLaumeister is right,  [see this test](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/hash/index.html#moreInfo) it loads at the specified spot the resets to the top and scrolls down. The OP could dispense with the scrolling though and just load to that section...which would be less jarring IMHO

Comment: @DelightedD0D Maybe I'm wrong about what a smooth scroll is, but that's what I would call what I'm getting when I go to your test... The speed could be slowed too to help with the transition--try making it 3000, nice and slow. Thanks for throwing that test together :-)

Comment: Are you opening the link in a new tab? If so you're probably missing the event. Click the link directly and you should see that it actually loads the page with the "moreInfo Div here" text already at the top of the window, then in jumps back up to the top and **then**  it smooth scrolls to the section. I missed it at first too but definitely happens

Comment: It may also depend on how fast the browser loads the page, I would expect that it would be more noticeable on a page with a lot of content. Though, I personally think that loading the page directly to the div without the "smooth scroll" is a better approach, in which case `<a id='about' href="index.html#moreInfo">about</a>` by itself would be sufficient

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting a GET parameter on the link URL then reading that parameter when the next page loads:

**collection.html**

```
<a id='about' href="index.html?scrollTo=moreInfo">about</a>
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
          var scrollTo = getParameterByName('scrollTo');
          if(scrollTo!=''){
              $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("#"+scrollTo).offset().top
               }, 1000);
          }
   });

   function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve smooth scrolling using html only

your page contains div like

```
<div id="sample">
</div>
```

You have to scroll to this div using

```
<a href="#sample">click here to scroll</a>
```

and simply use below code in your css

```
<style>
    html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

</style>
```