# Anchor tag does not redirect to div in responsible mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="navibar">
    <a class="naviitem" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="naviitem" href="index.html#discounts">Discounts</a>
    <a class="naviitem" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="discounts">Content</div>
```

The 'Discounts' button scrolls down the page until the `div id="discounts"` displays at the top of the screen on the desktop view. However when I'm in the responsive mobile view, it changes the URL to `something.com/index.html#discounts` but remains at the top of the index page. All other links are working.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the full path from the link.

```
<a class="naviitem" href="#discounts">Discounts</a>
```

Comment: You're assuming that the current view *is* index.html.

Comment: If you have multiple pages, you may need JS too. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621042/6767060).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still does not work in mobile view.